# how to make a test if the ball reached the hole?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am making really simple app in xcode.

And I want to make, if the ball reach the hole the game should finish

So i tried to make.

```
if (ball . center == hole.center )
```

and another ways and I failed

and I also tried this

```
(ball.frame.origin.x == hole.frame.origin.x && ball.frame.origin.y == hole.frame.origin.y)
```

And as usual failed

Please help.

i just want if the fram of the ball touches the hole The Game FINISH

Answer (score 6):

Problem is that you shouldn't check for a position to be exactly the same, that's not how it works with floating point coordinates (which I guess you are using) and precision of movement of things in games which cannot require to have object on same indentical position.

You should rather check if distance is less than a threshold:

```
float bx = ball.frame.origin.x;
float by = ball.frame.origin.y;

float hx = hole.frame.origin.x;
float hy = hole.frame.origin.y;

// you don't actually need abs since you are going to raise to the power of 2
// but for sake of soundness it makes sense
float dx = abs(bx-hx);
float dy = abs(by-hy);

if (sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) < THRESHOLD) {
  // the ball is enough near to center
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CGRectIntersectsRect` ([more on CGGeometry](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html)) to see if the ball and hole intersect eachother:

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, hole.frame)) {
    // Goal reached!
}
```

... or `CGRectEqualToRect` the same way (if you want to check if the frames are exactly the same).

Comment: That is useful when you have rect shaped boxes but not with circle shaped ones, unfortunately this will make a ball intersect the hole in situations which are rather unbelievable (like by considering intersection over 2 corners)

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you do not want to test whether the two centers are equal, but whether they are close enough to eachother. For example less then epsilon away in the x and y direction.